# One to many relationship use attach or save

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.3

I have two tables called notification and `alerFrequencies` table, and they have ont to many relationship respectively. the `notification_id` is a foreign key in the `alertFrequencies` table. the notification table has `id` and website URL fields and the `alerFrequncies` table has `id`, `notification_id` and `created_at` fields.

I am trying to insert data automatically into the `alertFrequencies` table using the following function, but failed to do so, it complained about the attach function?

```
private function add(Notification $notification,alertFrequency $alert, $alertTime){
    $notification->alertFrequencies()->attach($alert,
                            ['created_at'=>date($alertTime)]);
}
```

Comment: Please include the exact error message (and use the quote markup) when including it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [update()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method) instead of [attach()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) since it is `one to many` relation. Attach used in `many to many` ralations

```
private function add(Notification $notification,alertFrequency $alert, $alertTime){ 
    $notification->alertFrequencies()->update(['created_at'=>date($alertTime)]); 
}
```

Edit---

To answer your comment [register](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-mutators#date-mutators) `created_at` and `updated_at` field in `$dates` array in your `Notification` model like this.

```
protected $dates = [
    'created_at',
    'updated_at'
];
```

And when you saving your data as follows using [Carbon](http://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/)

```
    $notification->alertFrequencies()->update(['created_at'=>Carbon::parse($alertTime)]);
```

Comment: update works perfect but in keeps updating the update_at columns and changes the created_at to 00:00:00, and also makes to lose data records, do you think or suggest may be a better way?

Answer (score 0):

[Attach](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#updating-many-to-many-relationships) is used to create many-to-many relations.

To create one-to-many relations you simply set the `notification_id` of your `alertFrequency` object and save it.

Comment: I used save it don't complain as a fact but failed to save it. i don't see new records in the database